# Programmatically Create UIView with Custom Class (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to have a viewController (graphsVC) on which there will be a data entry field and 6 to 10 buttons for the user to select a graph type.

I'd like to programmatically:

- create a UIView on this viewController in which the selected graph will be drawn depending on which button is pressed.
- assign the UIView a particular class based on a button the user selects (each class uses `draw` to create the selected graph).
- if the user then selects a different button, I want to remove that UIView and recreate it with a different class corresponding to that choice.
- if the user changes the data, I want the graph to update itself.

Basically this pseudo-code:

```
func createViewWithCustomClass(selectedGraph)
{ 
   create new UIView on graphsVC with selectedGraph's class
   set view parameters for selected graph
}

func buttonX (selectedGraph) 
    remove previous view
    create new view with new class
}
```

So, I began with this :

```
func createGraphView(selectedGraph: Int) {
   let graphView = UIView.init()
   // set view's size, location, colors, etc. according to selectedGraph 
   switch selectedGraph {
       case 0: // set custom parameters for graph 0
       case 1: // set custom parameters for graph 1
       //  etc.
       default: break
   }
}
```

Each button has code similar to this:

```
@IBAction func buttonGraph0(_ sender: UIButton) {
    graphView.removeFromSuperView()  // remove existing view
    createGraphView(selectedGraph: 0)  // create new view (how to assign another class???)
}
```

But this button's function does not have access to the `graphView`.  So I moved `let graphView = UIView.init()` outside the function but now don't know how to assign it a class.  (Clearly I am floundering!)

```
var graphView = UIView.init()
func createGraphView(selectedGraph: Int) {
   // set graph size, location, colors, etc.
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out to be EXTREMELY simple: just a single line: `graphView = SelectedClassName()`!

```
var graphView = UIView()

func createGraphView(selectedGraph: Int) {

    // remove old graph
    graphView.removeFromSuperView

    // assign class
    switch selectedGraph {
        case 0: graphView = Class0()
        case 1: graphView = Class1()
        //  etc.
        default: break
    }

    // add graph 
    view.addSubview(graphView)
}
```

Comment: Whoever downgraded this, would you care to explain why?  Is there a problem doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a view controller for each graph type. Then in your createViewWithCustomClass, just assign the VC to use the UIView and let the new VC do the work. Here's an example;

```
   var graphTypeVCNames = ["graph1VC", "graph2VC", "graph3VC"]
   let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: graphTypeVCNames[selectedGraph]) // as! CustomViewController
    vc.view.frame = subView.bounds
    self.addChild(vc)
    self.subView.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Also, you should remove each one when you add a new one.

Comment: I'm confused.  1) When you say, "write a view controller for each graph type", could those view controllers be the classes for each graph?  (Those classes do exactly what I want when run individually.)  (I'm pretty new and don't understand the UIStoryboard object.)

Comment: Yes, each vc is a class which draws a different type of graph. The storyboard lets you build a graphic description of objects (a "view") and associate it with a class which manages it (ie-the "view controller"). The example above lets you assign a view controller to a subcomponent of larger view (with its own view controller).

Comment: Ok, (I think) it makes sense, but I get a "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException" error on the UIStoryboard line.

To be clear, "graph1VC", "graph2VC", and "graph3VC" are the class names for each graph UIView?  
For example, "class graph1VC: UIView {...}"  ?  (Of course, since the class would begin with a capital, "Graph1VC", I feel like I'm doing something wrong...)

Comment: No, UIViewController. Each controller draws into a view. you make the view they draw into the view in your main view when you do the addChild in the code above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying to create 10 new viewControllers (each of which must have an identifier and be connected to the originating vc with the input field and the buttons).  When a button is pressed, a new vc opens, the UIView is created, and the graph drawn.  If that is the case, it's not really what I want since I want the user to be able to change the data and have the graph update in real time.

I rephrased my original question to clarify.

Comment: Is there not a way to programmatically create a new UIView on one existing UIViewController, assign it a class, and remove that view to recreate it with a different class on that same UIViewController?

Comment: I recommend that you start by writing a view controller and using it to draw into a subview using the example above. you'll see how it works.

Comment: I did.  And it does work.  Just not what I'm looking for.  Unless I'm missing something else.