# Conflicting Constraint that does not conflict (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am rearranging three views like this when the phone is rotated:

[image] [image]

I set constraints as follows:

```
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    func setConstraints1() {
        
        let cv1Height: CGFloat = 325
        let cv3Height: CGFloat = 125
        
        cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // wh
        narrowConstraints = [
            
            // set cv1 height
            cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv1Height),
            // lock top, left and right to safe area
            cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),

            // lock left and right to safe area
            cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            
            // lock top of cv2 to bottom of cv1
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor),
            // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
            cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),
            
            // set cv3 height
            cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
            // lock left, right and bottom to safe area
            cv3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            cv3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ]
        
        wideConstraints = [

            // lock top, bottom, and left to safe area
            cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            // lock right side of cv1 to left side of cv2
            cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.leadingAnchor),
            
            // lock right side of cv2 to safe area
            cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            // lock top of cv2 to safe area
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            // lock bottom of cv2 to top of cv3
            cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv3.topAnchor),

            // set cv3 height
            cv3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv3Height),
            // lock bottom and right side of cv3 to safe area
            cv3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            
            // make them all equal widths
            cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor),
            cv3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv2.widthAnchor),            
        ]
        
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            // if landscape
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        else { // portrait
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            if size.width > size.height {
                // we're transitioning to wider than tall
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.narrowConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.wideConstraints)
            } else {
                // we're transitioning to taller than wide
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.wideConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.narrowConstraints)
            }
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // if you want to do something after the transition
            //self.cv2.setNeedsDisplay()
        })
    }
```

It all appears to work perfectly - except for the following error message:

```
2020-10-16 14:33:57.364778-0600 ViewPositions2[38358:6108060] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9130 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.height == 325   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa800 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.top == UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa3f0 V:[UIView:0x7fb41950ad90]-(0)-[UIView:0x7fb41950dec0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9ea0 UIView:0x7fb41950dec0.bottom == UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9c70 UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.height == 125   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033aa2b0 UIView:0x7fb41950e8f0.bottom == UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339ff20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0.height == 375   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339b840 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000339b7a0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-top' V:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000029bcb60'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x7fb41950f1c0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000033a9130 UIView:0x7fb41950ad90.height == 325   (active)>
```

Through trial and error, I figured out that this error message occurs if the sum of `cv1Height` and `cv2Height` exceeds 375 (the view height in landscape).

But, not only am I deactivating `narrowConstraints` when in landscape, `cv1` is never on top of `cv3` in landscape!

Why is this conflict occurring?  How do I prevent it???

Comment: When and how often are you calling `setConstraints1()`?

Comment: I update it in ````viewWillTransition````.  It should update whenever the screen is rotated from portrait to landscape and vice versa.  I've added that function in the original post.

Comment: [wtfautolayout](https://www.wtfautolayout.com) points to a table view or collection view causing the problem - the encapsulated view

Comment: Interesting!  But I don't understand...  I don't see the "encapsulated view" you mention.  It also adds a 4th view that I don't know what I should do with, if anything.

Comment: Please don't repeat your own questions - or your own answers, for that matter.

Comment: I got no answers and a downgrade with no reason, so I changed the question.  I did not repeat any of my own answers.

Comment: Well I could be wrong about the similarity of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897417/341994 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897611/341994

Comment: They are basically the same idea, but I changed this one to be different enough to get some attention.  When this was closed, I copied it and pasted it to the other.  I come here for help after spending hours trying to figure something out.  Being downgraded, which never has a reason, is not helpful and reduces any traffic to that question.

This question was closed before I had a chance to delete the previous one and now I can't delete it.  It is very frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the priority of the fixed height constraint to something lower than `.required`

```swift
let fixedHeightConstraint = cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: cv1Height)
fixedHeightConstraint.priority = .required - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work for me.